# Remove multiple rows from a list of names in R (a list of 187 names to remove)?

Tags: r, dataset, filtering, rows

I have a data frame in R containing over 29,000 rows. I need to remove multiple rows using only a list of names (187 names).

My dataset is about airlines, and I need to remove specific airlines from my data set that contains over 200 types of airlines. My first column contains all airline names, and I need to remove the entire row for those specific airlines.

I singled out all airline names that I want removed by this code: `transmute(a_name_remove, airline_name)`. This gave me a table of all names of airlines that I want removed, now I have to remove that list of names from my original dataset named **airlines**.

I know there is a way to do this manually, which is: `mydata[-c("a", "b"), ]`, for example. But writing out each name would be hectic.

Can you please help me by giving me a way to use the list that I have to forwardly remove those rows from my dataset?

I cannot write out each name on its own.
I also tried this: `airlines[!(row.names(airlines) %in% c(remove)), ]`, in which I made my list "removed" into a data frame and as a vector, then used that code to remove it from my original dataset "airlines", still did not work.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Noora, I think you are pretty close, but I think it will be easier to nail down the exact problem if you provide samples of your data. Can you provide a sample with `dput(airlines[1:50,])` and `dput(remove[1:10])`?

Comment: Hi, If you have all the row names to remove stored in `remove`, then: `airlines[-remove,]` should work

Comment: You can use the dplyr filter function here. 
`myData <- dplyr::filter(myData,  ! airline_name %in% remove)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that negates %in%, e.g.

```
'%not_in%' <- Negate('%in%')
```

so per your code, it should look like this

```
airlines[row.names(airlines) %not_in% remove, ]
```

additionally, I do not recommend using remove as a variable name, since it is a base function in R, if possible rename the variable, e.g. discard_airlines ,

```
airlines[row.names(airlines) %not_in% discard_airlines, ]
```

Comment: Why would you create a new function when you can just use a `!`?